# Why is the length of a non-empty array is 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

There is a code, in it I create links by data and put into an array:

```js
function Blogs(props) {
    const links = [];
    props.ids.forEach(id => {
        fetch(`${root}/api/blog/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                const link = <Link to={`/blog/${id}`}>{_.get(res, 'blog.name', '')}</Link>
                links.push(link);
            })
    });
    console.log(links.length) // 0
    return (
        <div className="profile-blogs">
            <div className="a">Блоги</div>
            <div className="b">
                {links}               {/* nothing */}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I consoling a `links`:

[image]

Why `links.length === 0` and how to fix it?

Comment: `fetch()` is **asynchronous**.  The `.then()` functions will run when the HTTP request completes.

Comment: Your `console.log` is written **after** the `fetch` but in reality `fetch` is **called after** because it needs time to fetch... so the code moves on to the `console.log` while the `fetch` code is still waiting for data. This is a *simplified* explanation.

Comment: You need to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use two of the react hooks; `useState` for links array, `useEffect` for fetch function.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR
do below changes :

```
async function Blogs(props) {
  const links = [];
  for(let id of props.ids){
       const res = await fetchLink(id);
       const link = <Link to={`/blog/${id}`}>{_.get(res, 'blog.name', '')}</Link>
       links.push(link);
  }
  const fetchLink = async(id) =>{
    const result = await  fetch(`${root}/api/blog/${id}`);
    return result.json();
  }
  console.log(links.length) // 0
  return (
      <div className="profile-blogs">
          <div className="a">Блоги</div>
          <div className="b">
              {links}               {/* nothing */}
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

> But Why my code is not working ?

JS is asynchronous , it doesn't wait for any Async statement to finish. So if not handled properly, the next line of code which is intended to be executed after the async operation will execute.
`forEach` method will not execute your async code serially (I guess that is your assumption). So in the loop, all the element will run one by one (calling the `fetch` API) without waiting for the previous one to get completed(that is how JS works).
Finally it reaches to the next line i.e     `console.log(links.length)`   which prints `0` because your API call never finished before executing this line.

> Another important point :

Executing this  kind of code  in the component is not advisable because it will be re-executed every time the state is updated and component is re-rendered.
Such kind of code should be executed as `sideEffect` probably using the `useEffect` hook.
So that the code block is only executed when needed and not every time the component is rendered.

Comment: This is **not** how you should fetch and render asynchronously in React.

Comment: @EmileBergeron agreed. See my last paragraph. The first one where I corrected the code was to make him understand how Async code works. That is definitely not the React way of doing.

Comment: It unfortunately makes your answer misleading.